# Support libraries version issue

Tags: android

I am trying to import a project from github. Below are the dependencies I am using

```
dependencies {
provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.3'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.+'

compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:11.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:11.0.1'

testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.+'
}
```

But I am facing below error

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 26.0.0-alpha1, 25.2.0.
```

Examples include `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0-alpha1` and `com.android.support:percent:25.2.0`

It can be seen that I am using same library version with all dependencies but don't know why am I getting this error? What am I missing? As it is suggested in other threads of stackoverflow I have placed the same library version. Any help?

**Edit**

Below is some more information regrading gradle file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.uamp"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

When I tried below command to see what library using what version (as it was suggested in one thread over stack over flow) it says '**Task app not found in root project**'

```
gradlew -q dependencies app --configuration compile
```

Comment: one of your 3rd party libraries probably includes another library in it as a dependancy. Of which it is using a different version to the one you specified.

Comment: I am also thinking the same way. But how can I solve this?

Comment: You can either target the same version as the one they specified, remove their library, or try and get an updated version of their library that targets the same version. using + in the library version is not recommended btw.

Comment: first you have to check if really it's from other 3rd library, before that try to clean the code, remove .build file and rebuild the application.
if still there is an error, you have to try to remove the 3rd libraries one by one and check. if it's 3rd library issue, then you have to find new one or upgrade the library if it has new version.

Answer (score 2):

1. Run:

> gradlew application:dependencies

From your project directory.

2. Verify which dependency is using older version of `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable`.
3. Add explicitly:

> compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0-alpha1'

in your `build.gradle` along with your other dependencies and **after the library that uses the older version**.

Same for `percent` library.

It's very often issue. Personally, I struggle with similar problem when importing Facebook SDK library.

Answer (score 0):

After spending many hours at last I have solved my problem. Posting my answer it may help other. As suggested in the error I added updated library version as mentioned below. Error was saying

```
com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.0-alpha1
com.android.support:percent:25.2.0
```

And I replace above with below code and that worked for me

```
  compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
  compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.+'
```